# Is it possible to load remote javascript that uses local assets (with respect to itself)?

Tags: javascript, html, assets

I want a webpage to execute a remotely hosted js script. The script makes use of image-assets within the script's *own* directory. Is this possible to do using only relative filepaths within the script?

When run remotely, the relative filepath is interpreted as relative-to-the-webpage-file, not relative to the remote script itself.

I'd like to handle this without modifying the script to use absolute paths, because it's intended to be transportable. The webpage is just a showcase  for the project. Is this possible to do in HTML?

Specifically, I have a javascript file being served by github pages eg:

`https://user.github.io/repo/script.js`

which uses some image assets, located in that repo, eg:

`https://user.github.io/repo/assets/image.png`

The script uses local paths to load its assets, eg:

```
imgBird = loadImage('assets/bird.png');
```

This doesn't work when the script is loaded remotely, because the script looks within the directory of the webpage for `assets/bird.png`, not the remote resource.

The HTML source currently uses the following to attempt to run the script:

```
<script src="https://user.github.io/repo/script.js">
```

There exists a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54441836/7275901), but the answer is script-based. I want to avoid modifying how the script works because it's intended to be introductory-level scripting and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Paths are relative to the page containing the script tag, not the script itself. For the script to function correctly it will need to know the url for `/assets`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to edit the script. Add hostname variable and then add it to the path

```
const hostname = 'https://user.github.io/repo/'

imgBird = loadImage(`${hostname}assets/bird.png`);
```

And then you can just change the hostname variable later to different one when you'll move the project